# Can't change label for prototype cell in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cell

I have a prototype cell with label

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *itemName;
```

declared in class ECOMAdmPanelViewCell and the class is set for the cell in Identity inspector. The outlet itemName - Label is created.

In this function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"admPanelCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[ECOMAdmPanelViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.itemName.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

I get an error message property 'itemName' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell'. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your this line

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with this

```
 ECOMAdmPanelViewCell *cell = (ECOMAdmPanelViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"admPanelCell";
    ECOMAdmPanelViewCell *cell = (ECOMAdmPanelViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[ECOMAdmPanelViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.itemName.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or use this:

```
(ECOMAdmPanelViewCell *)cell.itemName
```